# Upgrade from PHP5 to PHP7 causes long TTFB

Tags: php, apache, performance, php-7

## The issue

I recently upgraded PHP on my server from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0, for some reason this has caused an incredibly long TTFB (compared to before).

## Quick overview of how I set up my website

My website uses a combination of client and server side optimizations to make my run at an insane speed (average of 250ms for an initial full page load), causing as little overhead for the users as possible.

However, ever since I upgraded to PHP 7.0, the time to first byte increased from around 50ms up to anywhere from 700ms to 2000ms (which feels like an eternity compared to the load times before this).

## The question

I was wondering if there are known performance issues with PHP 7.0 compared to PHP 5.6, and if so how I could fix them. Thank you for your time

Comment: My server takes 0.0085s for a full page load and all I've done is use native php code, sorry I don't have any advice

Comment: Are we talking mod php or FPM?

Comment: @Dale I'm using mod php

Comment: Hmmm.. we recently upgraded to php 7.0.6 and haven't noticed anything detrimental.. Ubuntu, Apache2 and mod PHP

Comment: @Dale yup, using that exact same setup

Comment: We did however run into a ton of apache2 segfaults.. until the repo was updated yesterday.. sorry I can't really help here

Comment: @Dale thanks for the help nonetheless :)

Comment: Actually PHP7 is faster than PHP5.x, on my server over 2x than with 5.6. Well,  I am using Nginx with PHP-FPM. There has to be something that makes such a huge impact. Try to debug your script and find the bottleneck, also check the installed extensions. Extensions like Xdebug slow scripts extremely down and aren't even needed on a production server.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I sadly already disabled all Apache and PHP modules that I don't use, and the script (running it from the CLI on the server) runs as it would usually (pretty insanely fast)

Comment: How do you measure the load time? Did you measure the pure php execution time yet? If the pure php time is what you expect to be (pretty fast), then the webserver is your cause (generally I wouldn't use apache if you need speed).

Comment: 2 seconds is quite a pause. I would check if there is anything suspicious in [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I measured the execution time of my script by using `microtime(true)` statements at the beginning and end of my script, which after +/- 10 tests showed the slowest request being `0.0046639442443848s`